# can not operand "+=" cells of sheets in epplus

Tags: epplus

nevertheless i change all cells of sheets in **epplus** to double sheets,but the error operand += happen in my code.this is my code.

```
sheet.Cells["C1:C"+sheet.Dimension.Rows].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";
//sheet.Cells["C1:C" + sheet.Dimension.Rows].Value = s;
for (int x = 1; x <= sheet2.Dimension.Rows; x++)
{
   for (int y = 1; y <= sheet.Dimension.Rows; y++)
   {
       if (sheet.Cells[y, 1].Value.ToString() != null)
       {
           if (sheet2.Cells[x, 1].Value.Equals(sheet.Cells[y, 1].Value.ToString()))
           {
               sheet2.Cells[x, 4].Value.GetType<Double>() += sheet.Cells[y, 3].Value.GetType<Double>();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your help
your resolve help me to solve my code tnx. this is the resolution of code.

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 604; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y <= sheet.Dimension.Rows; y++)
                {
                    if (sheet.Cells[y, 1].Value.ToString() != null)
                    {
                        if (sheet.Cells[y, 1].Value.Equals(sheet2.Cells[x, 1].Value.ToString()))
                        {

                            double cellValue = Convert.ToDouble(sheet2.Cells[x, 4].Value);
                            cellValue += Convert.ToDouble(sheet.Cells[y, 3].Value);
                            sheet2.Cells[x, 4].Value = cellValue;
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is because you are trying to `+=` a getter function. You can only do that operation in objects that can be assigned values.

You could for example do the following

```
if (sheet2.Cells[x, 1].Value.Equals(sheet.Cells[y, 1].Value.ToString()))
{
    double cellValue = (double)sheet2.Cells[x, 4].Value;
    cellValue += (double)sheet.Cells[y, 3].Value;
    sheet2.Cells[x, 4].Value = cellvalue;
}
```

Edit: The following is untested, but could also work: `((double)sheet2.Cells[x, 4].Value) += (double)sheet.Cells[y, 3].Value`

Comment: thank you for help
but when i test your code,other error happen in visual studio
**Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0308 The non-generic method `object.GetType()` cannot be used with type arguments** and red line appear under `GetType<Double>();`

Comment: another error happened.**specific cast is not valid**.

Comment: tnx for your help